# How to access BLOB file from database table published to ArcGIS REST service

Tags: arcgis-server, image

I have published a query table that contains a BLOB field to ArcGIS REST and have not been able to access the images. I tried using esriRequest, but the response type that returns is text, and I think it should be image. I don't know if this is because there is something about the files the REST service doesn't like, or if I am missing something in the code. The images are currently being served out using PHP the query the SQL database. Here is the code I am trying to use to get the images:

```
var imageUrl = "https://ocean.floridamarine.org/arcgis/rest/services/.../MapServer/1/7";
    var params = {
        url: imageUrl,
        handleAs: "blob"
    }
    console.log("request params ", params);
    var imageRequest = esriRequest(params);
    imageRequest.then(requestSucceeded, requestFailed);
    function requestSucceeded(response, io) {
        console.log("esriRequest response ", response);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        if (response.type == "image/png") {
          //if working with image data
          reader.readAsDataURL(response);
          console.log("image response ", response);
        } else {
          reader.readAsText(response);
          console.log("reader response ", reader.readAsText(response));
        }
    };
    function requestFailed(error, io) {
       temp = temp + "<br/><div  style='text-align:center;'><strong>No Image Available</strong></div>";
       console.log(error);
    }
```

The url points to this, but not sure if I should be seeing an image here:
[image: rest service endpoint]

Here is a screenshot of the console:
[image: console]

As you can see, the response type is text (should be seeing an image?)

What I am doing wrong? Is a better way to go about this?

Comment: Is this a Web AppBuilder app, or just straight Esri JavaScript?

Comment: The app was created using Web AppBuilder version 2.12. The images are currently being accessed on the server side using php. I don't have any specific knowledge about how the images are being written to the sql database, but I know they are submitted by the public through a web form. I am thinking that this is either a compatibility issue with ArcGIS (since the images were not inserted into the database by ArcMap), or maybe I am using the wrong method to try and extract them.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications or additional information that may help to attract a potential answerer..